# How to get different types of mobile numbers from contacts in android?

Tags: android, contacts

Using the following Code:

`int index3 = phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);` 
But it only gets one number and i also don't know which type of number it is. I want to get phone of type mobile , work , home etc. What would be the code for that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out you can simply use a switch statement on the TYPE and get different numbers and their type

**CODE:**

```
       while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                int index3 = phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                int type = phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);
                int type1 = phoneCursor.getInt(type);

                switch (type1) {
                    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                        numberWork = phoneCursor.getString(index3);
                        break;
                    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                        numberMobile = phoneCursor.getString(index3);
                        break;
                    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                        numberHome = phoneCursor.getString(index3);
                        break;

                }
            }
```